# Checkout price different from cart price using woocommerce_product_get_price hook

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I´m running a WooCommerce (WordPress 6.1.1 and WooCommerce 7.3.0), and I´m trying to set prices according to the user role.
To do this I have introduced a new field named Webprice (precio_web) in product definition using the plugin: "Advanced Custom Fields". Customer users and not logged users must use this special price.
Also I added this code in my functions.php child-theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'ui_custom_price_role', 99, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'ui_custom_price_role', 99, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'ui_custom_price_role', 99, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'ui_custom_price_role', 99, 2);

function ui_custom_price_role($price, $product) {
    $price = ui_custom_price_handling($price, $product);
    return $price;
}
Variable add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'ui_custom_variable_price', 99, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'ui_custom_variable_price', 99, 3);

function ui_custom_variable_price($price, $variation, $product) {
    $price = ui_custom_price_handling($price, $product);
    return $price;

    function ui_custom_price_handling($price, $product) {

        //get our current user

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        //check if the user role is the role we want or is not logged

        if ((!is_user_logged_in()) || (isset($current_user - \ > roles\[0\]) && '' != $current_user - \ > roles\[0\] && in_array('customer', $current_user - \ > roles))) { //load the custom price for our product $custom_price = get_post_meta( $product-\>get_id(), 'precio_web', true );

            // custom price

            if (!empty($custom_price)) {
                $price = $custom_price;
            }
        }

        return $price;
    }
}
```

So far It works, when adding items to the cart I can see the new price.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OakYA.png)

The problem is at checkout for some reason prices displayed are the standard, not the ones corresponding to the new field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C88Q1.png)

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

I was expecting that the modification of the get_price function was enough because the prices are displayed correctly. However, the order is recorded with the standard price of the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce recalculates all prices during the checkout process multiple times, so you need to hook into this recalculation also. This should work for you:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'update_cart_price'), 99);

function update_cart_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item = $cart_item['data'];
        $cart_item_product_id =  $cart_item->get_id(); 
        $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item_product_id );
        $orig_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $new_price = ui_custom_price_handling( $orig_price, $product );
        $cart_item->set_price( $new_price );
    }
}
```